# Ember updating video sources but not being reflected by browser

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, client-side

I have an ember application with nested resources in which I'm showing videos. The outer resource (videos) simply displays all of the videos. When you click a video the nested `video` resource is activated and a title/player is shown.

This works great the *first* time you click something. The video shows up and it plays. HOWEVER, when clicking another video, the nested resource video is updated and the DOMs `<source>` gets updated but the OLD video continues to play! Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

[Working Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyledecot/rverobx9/)

Comment: My guess is that the source tag doesn't support dynamically modifying the src after it's loaded.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-source-element, Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect.

Comment: Interesting @Kingpin2k How would one go about solving this in an "ember" way?

Comment: Why does the fiddle use Ember 1.0.0? Are you stuck using that version or would it be possible to use a later one?

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice I can use any version. What would the newer version gain me in regards to this particular issue?

Comment: I thought you might be able to cut down on the amount of code in my answer by calling `route.refresh()` (added in 1.4.0) but after testing it seems like that wouldn't work.

Comment: There are a lot of good (and IMHO correct answers) in this thread. Why did you not reward the bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a component to create the video player, and wrap up the rerender logic in the component.

The component would look something like

```
App.VideoPlayerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  src: null,  
  rerenderPlayer: function(){
    if(this.$()) {
      Ember.run.debounce(this, this.rerender, 200);
    }
  },
  srcObserver: function(){
    this.rerenderPlayer();
  }.observes('src')
});
```

and the component template would look like

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/video-player">
  <video controls>
  <source {{bind-attr src=src}} type = "video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
</script>
```

You would then be able to just reference the component in your template like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="video">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  {{video-player src=src}}
</script>
```

You can see a working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fehipa/2/edit

---

As a bonus.. If you created a video player component you would also be able to wrap up the ability to pause and play the video in the component. So that you can have a totally reusable video player to use anywhere in your app.

Comment: Within your component definition, you should create a separate function that first ensure's the view is still in the DOM before calling rerender. Then you should debounce that function. Otherwise, race conditions and fast integration tests can trigger assertions when the debounce fires and the view is not in the DOM. Otherwise, +1

Comment: Why use debounce over one of the other `Ember.run` functions? Also, if debounce is really what should be used why 200ms? Is that just an arbitrary number you selected?

Comment: `debounce` is just so that if the src changes more than once in succession it doesnt kick off the rerender until it stops changing for 200ms. As for the 200ms yes its pretty much arbitrary but it should be a number that feels responsive but still stops the app from rerendering incessantly.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `{{bind-attr src="src"}}` from the `<source>` element up to the `<video>` element, it just works without any hacks.

your code would change from:

```
<video controls>
  <source {{bind-attr src="src"}} type = "video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

to

```
<video controls {{bind-attr src="src"}}></video>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfmzwhxx/

Comment: Well my example is somewhat oversimplified. I have multiple sources for supporting different devices. Otherwise, yes this would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but this can be achieved by rerendering the view. Add the following code:

```
App.VideoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    oldVideoId: null,
    afterModel: function (resolvedModel) {
        if (this.get('oldVideoId') !== resolvedModel.id) {
            this.set('oldVideoId', resolvedModel.id);
            $.each(Ember.View.views, function( i, view ) {
                if (view.renderedName === "videos"){
                   view.rerender();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cz6pL22/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this. Even though this does work I'm going to wait a little while before awarding any points to see if there is a move elegant solution out there.

Comment: I think the sentiment of rerendering the view is right. But It's not the route's job to do this. A view should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a similar approach to @AlliterativeAlice, but I would definitely **not recommend** doing this operation at the route level. This problem is a consequence of DOM security and thus is a job for the view. You're best bet is to setup an observer in your view class and call rerender from there. E.g.:

```
App.VideoView = Ember.View.extend({
  _didChangeVideoSrc: function() {
    // Make the view is still in the DOM
    if(this.$()) {
      this.rerender();
    }
  }.observes('controller.src')
});
```

I also updated your fiddle to make this work: http://jsfiddle.net/rverobx9/2/

Answer (score 0):

While answers suggesting to re-render in any way might solve your problem, if you have access to the API of the player it'd be nice to see if stopping the video in the `willDestroyElement` of your view won't fix that.

Also you could have your video player being an Ember component, ensuring good setup, teardown and update:

```
App.VideoPlayerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    source: null, // used in the template using that component
    isPlayerReady: false, // used to know internally if the player is ready

    setupPlayer: (function(){
      // somehow setup the video player if needed
      // (if Flash player for example, make the flash detection and whatever)
      // once ready, trigger our `videoPlayerReady` event
      this.set('isPlayerReady', true);
      this.trigger('videoPlayerReady');
    }).on('didInsertElement'),

    updatePlayerSource: (function(){
      // start playing if we have a source and our player is ready
      if ( this.get('isPlayerReady') && this.get('source') )
      {
        // replace with the correct js to start the video
        this.$('.class-of-player').videoPlay(this.get('source'));
      }
    }).observes('source').on('videoPlayerReady'),

    teardownSource: (function(){
      // stop playing if our player is ready since our source is going to change
      if ( this.get('source') && this.get('isPlayerReady') )
      {
        // replace with the correct js to stop the player
        this.$('.class-of-player').videoStop();
      }
    }).observesBefore('source'),

    teardownPlayer: (function(){
      // teardown the player somehow (do the opposite of what is setup in `setupPlayer`)
      // then register that our player isn't ready
      this.set('isPlayerReady', false);
    }).on('willDestroyElement')
});
```

This will allow you to be sure everything is setup and teardown correctly, and since it's a component you can re-use, it'll be very easy to have a fallback to a flash player for example. Then whatever you have to handle and fix stuff related to the player, it will be in that component, and you'll just have to replace the part of your template with the player with:

```
{{video-player source=ctrl.videoUrl}}
```

Comment: Why did someone downvote this answer? Is there a negative here I'm not seeing?